# Microsoft Service: XmlDocument.Load could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, xml, ssl

It runs on my computer but when I upload to Server it gets this error

```
New Log created: 16.05.2020 16:28:32
Error: System.Net.WebException: *The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.*
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
```

PS:Project .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2

Comment: There are few possibilities 1)  There is a different version of Net on Server.  So make sure you publish application and install using setup.exe 2) The TLS/SSL port number is blocked. 3)  Local Computer may allow non secure http connections while server may require https.  The https is using SSL/TLS.

Comment: Is this problem caused by a vpn

Comment: If you have a route to the server than it is not a vpn issue.  You can always try from cmd.exe >Ping IP to see if you have a route to the server.